# How to Verify Email to see if it is exist in Code Igniter?

Tags: codeigniter, email-validation

I have created a form for add user which contain email, password, firstname, and lastname. I want to verify the email to see whether it is already exit or not yet?

How can I do that? any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

*you can create a callback function to check wether an email exist or not using your model like that*
**Controller**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("email","Email","required|callback_isEmailExist");
```

**now create a callback function in your controller**

```
function isEmailExist($email)
{
$verifyemail = $this->model_name->verifyemail($email)
if($verifyemail == true)
{
return false;
}
else{
return true;
}
}
```

**Model**

```
function verifyemail($email)
{
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("table_name");
$this->db->where("email",$email);
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() == 1)
{ 
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this --

controller -- school.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class School extends CI_Controller {

public function registration()
      {
        $this->load->view('registration');
      }

public function insert()
{
    $data = $_POST;
    $email = $data['email'];
    $result = $this->school_model->checkEmail($email);
    if(empty($result))
    {
        $this->school_model->insertData($data);
        $msg = "Data Insert Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "Email Already Exists";
    }
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);
    redirect('school/registration');
}

}

?>
```

model -- school_model.php

```
<?php 
class School_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function checkEmail($email)
        {
           $this -> db -> select('*');
           $this -> db -> from('users');
           $this -> db -> where('email', $email);
           $query = $this -> db -> get();
           return $query->result_array();
        }

    public function insertData($data)
        {
            $this->db->insert('users', $data);
        }
}
?>
```

view -- registration.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="show_flash_msg"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?></div>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>school/insert">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    Password: <input type="text" name="password">
    Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why woulnd you use the form_validation of codeigniter which has it's own in-build function to check if something is unique? You could just use  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');

Comment: yes we can also use that method but for form validation HTML5 validation is best because it`s check form without refreshing the page and in ci form validation it`s refresh the page... so it will be best way

Comment: You should not be depending on HTML validations, besides, you're still doing a refresh since you have no ajax. You will still post like always. Your method does not provide anything extra. Along with that, there is no reason to do $this->db->select("*") when you only want to count the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the form_validation of codeigniter you should add a rule as follow:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```